# How to get hover efect only on part of the element?

Tags: html, css

I have the below code:

```css
.container {
 padding-top:20px;
}

.container:hover {
 background-color: red;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.container:before {
content: 'before';
top: 5px;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='text'>
    My text
  </span>
</div>
```

I needed the 'before' as a title so inserted it as a pseudo, moved up and created palce for it by adding padding to the div. Now when I hover over the div the pseudo gets highlighted as well, which I don't want.

AS it's a skin for external app I have very limited possibilities to add elements to dom, which is what I guess should be done. How can I highlight only bottom part of the div without the pseudo? Maybe there's a better way to style the pseudo itself so that it doesn't get hovered over? Pure CSS appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent the background from covering the padding as well, add `background-clip: content-box;` to the `.container`:

```css
.container {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.container:before {
  content: 'before';
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='text'>
    My text
  </span>
</div>
```

Or use `margin-top: 20px;` instead of the padding:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.container:before {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  content: 'before';
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='text'>
    My text
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An simple solution is to use a margin-top on the container class instead of padding-top.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-clip: content-box;
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.container:before {
  content: 'before';
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='text'>
    My text
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try hover .text instead of .container and give "initial" or "transparent" background to the pseudo element.

*Just my $0.02:
I hope you understand that this whole thing is very strange, to say the least. It will limit any further customizations like font-height etc. Each time a new line of text will be added, you'll need to adjust padding or margin or top. Honestly, I don't understand what kind of app has such a strict skin that can't let you add an element.*

Answer (score 0):

Why not use descendant selectors? You can nest under `:hover` as well. And with `display: block;` no need to use fixed size margins and paddings either.

```css
.container:hover .text {
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  display: block; /* or just use a div instead */
}

.container:before {
  content: 'before';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <span class='text'>
    My text
  </span>
</div>
```